# Scrum teams vs. traditionally organized teams

Tags: agile, scrum, organization

To those of you who started using scrum in your development teams: Did you maintain the traditional teams or form new ones? At our organization we are split into database, product development and frontend developers (simplified!).

I am interested in whether others actually reorganized their whole team structure due to scrum or if you formed dedicated project (?) teams combining e.g. one person of each "old" team.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually can't even imagine how scrum could work if you maintain your role silos.  In scrum we build vertical slices through the product so that every feature delivered during a sprint requires all the skills you mentioned (plus QA which you did not).  How would you create continuous collaboration and have people commit to the sprint if they weren't all on the same team?  Seems like the most likely way to end in "Scrumfall" to me.  I'm not an expert by any means but it seems to me that the sure way to fail at scrum is to think of it as a project management solution instead of an entire organizational change. Its cultural at the core.

To answer you question about "generalists".  The easy answer is that by having certain people only able to work on certain things you create big fatty bottlenecks in getting to Done.  With specialties you are always constrained at each step by having limited resources to work on something.  In sprint 1 you may have a lot of db work to do where there is more than just that one dba can do.  But then in sprint 5 where there is no change to the datamodel at all, your dba will be sitting around keeping bored.  It becomes almost impossible in sprint planning to commit in a reasonable time if you have to divy up and assign at the task level by role instead of just grabbing the next set of priority features that fits your team's velocity.  The generalist model will inevitably bring business value in the long run.  You may just not see it right away until you achieve cross-pollination.

I would warn that if you are already in silo-ed groups by role, then you have to be very careful in am agile reorganization.  Many people are not ready and don't want to be ready to lose their special titles and just become team members.  I would think you should almost always expect some amount of turnover.

Answer (score 3):

It is preferred that in scrum/agile development that most individuals on the team are 'generalist' meaning that anyone can reasonably step into any role so that anyone can pull off items in the backlog as the come and nobody is waiting around for others.

now this may not be the case in your situation today but doing things such as peer programming and standup meetings to see where people are having impedements and to improve cross pollination of knowledge will help in obtaining this goal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if the "generalist" approach does not bring (business) value? E.g. does the database person really need to learn about CSS browser bugs? I understand that that could be accomplished through pair programming, but why?

Answer (score 1):

At my company we create a temporary cross function team for each project.  Our existing teams are still there, but it is really important that we have cross functional teams for scrum.

Answer (score 1):

We generally try to mix up a little bit to get some cross-team knowledge, but we for the most part work on our specialties. But as the project progresses we can more easily help out on different teams

Answer (score 1):

When I worked for my previous employer, the company reorg'ed the whole dev organization and product management. They put engineers, qa, and analysts in each team. The split was mostly vertical/functional with some exceptions. Those exceptions were a mistake - the architecture vertical did not fit, because it was really horizontal. I thought that cross-functional teams worked well. In your case, the db and front-end departments need to merge with the rest if possible, and new verticals specific to your product may be created

Answer (score 0):

We split our team into New Product Development and Existing Product Maintenance, with the ability for any developer to hop from one to the other between sprints.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have maintained the traditional team, at least for now.  There are a couple of other teams within the applications branch of the Information Systems department where I work though these were put in just before we got into Scrum.

There is a big project most of us are on that is using Scrum and the team seems to be evolving along nicely.  We have some new tools and processes that seem to have helped us a lot and given us a sense of "awesomeness" that hopefully we will pass on to the other teams.

For changes to a database, any of us developers can make the change in the development environment and then pass along the script to a DBA to be done when it is ready for production.  For changes to the network, there are infrastructure folks that handle that and initially setting up a server in terms of O/S, network, memory, hard drives, etc.